# Array of scalars and vectors at the same time in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, scalar

I have to create an **array** of the following "structure" in PHP:

`user_id,array(item_id,flag,array(feedback_message_id))`

Basically, for each `user_id`, there is an **array of (item_id, flag**, and an **array of feedback_messages**)..

Within a "classes" table, I have a field called "users" that holds data with separators. An example of data will be:
|1-5-1-1~2~5|2-3-4-5~6~7|.......

I would need to put the data into an array as follows:

```php
$myArray[0][0]="1";       // the first user's user_id = 0
$myArray[0][1][0]="5";    // the first user's first item's id = 5
$myArray[0][1][1]="1";    // the first user's first item's flag = 0
$myArray[0][1][2][0]="1"; // the first user's first item's first feedback message's id = 1
$myArray[0][1][2][1]="2"; // the first user's first item's second feedback message's id = 2
$myArray[0][1][2][2]="5"; // the first user's first item's third feedback message's id = 3
```

I don't know how to create such an array and how to retrieve data from it (syntax-wise)... I worked with single-dimensional arrays and multidimensional array, but this is an array partially bi-dimensional, partially tri and four-dimensional... is that even possible?

Comment: Create the array as you read rows from the database query.  Show your query.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!! In the database I will have a text field containing all the data with separators ( "|" between users, "-" between items,"~" between item properties and "," between feedback messages). The field should look like this: |userid-itemid~flag~fdbid1,fdbid2,fdbid3...|nextuser....and so on. I will read this using PHP explode function and would like to put everything in an array of the structure. My SQL query is just a SELECT * from, where one of the fields is the list of users with items with feedbacks...

Comment: Edit the question and show an example of that.

Comment: the list being this data block with separators

Comment: My problem is with the syntax of creating such an array....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case array $a represent single user so get data like:

```
$a=array( "user1", array( "item2", "DA", array ( "f1","f2","f3" ) ) );
$user = $a[1][2][1]; //f2
```

In common case it should be array of users:

```
<?php
$a = array( "user1", array( "item2", "DA", array ( "f1","f2","f3" ) ) ); 

var_export($a[1][2][1]);


$users = [
    ["user1", ["item2", "DA", [ "f1","f2","f3" ] ] ]
];

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL ."user" . PHP_EOL;
$user = $users[0];

var_export($user);

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL ."user item" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$user_item = $users[0][1][0];

var_export($user_item);

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL ."user flag" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$user_flag = $users[0][1][1];

var_export($user_flag);

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL ."user feedbacks" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$user_flag = $users[0][1][2];

var_export($user_flag);


echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL ."user second feedbacks" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$user_flag = $users[0][1][2][1];

var_export($user_flag);
```

[share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=90bbd2c8317239febeeca2ed854835be&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Thank you so much!! You understood exactly what I needed! :) It is way more elegant than my solution. THANK YOU!! I cannot vote for your answer, though, because I have less than 15 minutes reputation..

Comment: Now I saw the check icon :) I accepted it. THANK YOU again so much!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!

The thing was to create the array when inputing the values, instead of creating an empty structure beforehand:

$myArray=array(array("user1",array("item2","YES",array ("f1","f2","f3"))));

Then, I can recall, for example, "f2" with $myArray[0][1][2][1];

So I will make a function using PHP explode to read the data with separators from the "users" field of my "classes" table, and insert it into this array.

Thanks AbraCadaver for giving me the hint to create the array as I read from the DB!!! Only now, after 1 hour, it clicked for me :)

All the best!!
Ovi